# Plotting a third point given two points and a desired angle for the third point (and possibly a distance)

Tags: javascript, plot, trigonometry, angle

I am trying to plot a third point (C) given two points (A, B) and the angle I want the third point to be be at. I will also probably need a length for distance to plot that third point, but let's assume it's fixed for now. How can I take pontA (a.x, a.y), pointB (b.x, b.y), and an angle of (eg) 45 degrees and plot a third point (C) from this.[image]

Comment: there's probably some trigonometry involved ... what have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

This is a trigonometry problem.

```
// angle = the known angle
// dist = the distance from b to c

let angleAB = Math.atan2(a.y - b.y, a.x - b.x);

// if c is counterclockwise from a
c.x = b.x + dist*Math.cos(angleAB + angle)
c.y = b.y + dist*Math.sin(angleAB + angle)

// if c is clockwise from a
c.x = b.x + dist*Math.cos(angleAB - angle)
c.y = b.y + dist*Math.sin(angleAB - angle)
```

Note: angle should be in radians for this to work.

Comment: Thanks for this! Can you think of a way to know if you are going clockwise or counterclockwise?  Considering the A-B line could be in any direction.

Comment: What I meant by clockwise and counterclockwise in my post was if the angle ABC(the "known angle") was clockwise or counterclockwise. From your picture above, it appears to be clockwise.

Comment: Your code works for me in the case that  line A-B is on a flat plane but not when the A-B line is vertical or at a slant. I am working on a solution now and will post the code I am working with